# difference between assertNotTrue and assertFalse

Tags: php, phpunit, assert

I am looking at the documentation for phpunit.
Is there a difference between assertNotTrue and assertFalse?
Also assertTrue vs assertNotFalse?

Comment: Well, `"foo"` is _not true_ (with a type safe check!), but does that make it _false_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a dynamic language. A function is able to return a boolean in one case and any other type in another case. Let's look at the strrpos() function. It returns false if it did not find anything, but 0 if it has found something at the begining of the string.

So if the function returns the numeric 0 assertNotFalse is true, but assertTrue is false.

Comment: This is pretty much what said functions do. See the discussion and test cases supplied with [pull request #1103](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/1103)